# myfaces partialTriggers

Tags: triggers, partial, myfaces

Here is my myFaces Code the

```
<tr:commandButton text="Calculate Modulus" action="#{pageManager.form.calculateModulus}" id="modulusCalculation" partialSubmit="true"/> 

<tr:table value="#{pageManager.form.modulusCollection}" var="modulus" width="75%" 
        inlineStyle="align:center;" partialTriggers="modulusCalculation" autoSubmit="true">
    <tr:column headerText="Combination">
        <tr:outputLabel value="#{modulus.combination}" /> 
    </tr:column>
    <tr:column headerText="Modulus">
        <tr:outputLabel value="#{modulus.modulusValue}" />
    </tr:column>
</tr:table>
```

Here when I click a button I want my table to get refreshed but this does not happen
The button code has many lines and the lines that affect my table are:

```
HashMap<String, Object> modulusInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    modulusInfo.put("combination", combination);
    modulusInfo.put("modulusValue",modulus);
    modulusCollection.add(modulusInfo);
```

On my console I get the following error:

Dec 30, 2009 5:05:07 PM org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.RequestContextImpl addPartialTriggerListeners
WARNING: Could not find partial trigger modulusCalculation from CoreTable[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id_jsp_1481482420_15j_id_1]

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

in your table the partialTriggers="modulusCalculation" should look like this: partialTriggers=":modulusCalculation"